# Careers 2.0 tells me I must add a title and description to increase my completeness score

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have just created my Careers 2.0 portfolio but it is telling me that to increase my completeness score I must add a description and title to my "unnamed projects" when they are clearly named. When I click on the project it takes me to the editing of the named projects. I don't understand how to fix this, I have tried clearing my cache and logging in and out again.

It says:

```
Entered a name and description for each project (more...)
(Unnamed project) needs a description
(Unnamed project) needs a description
(Unnamed project) needs a description
(Unnamed project) needs a description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CV Project Name and Description should now correctly identify your projects.